# Wonder Gecko & freeRTOS: assertion in tickless mode

Tags: embedded, microcontroller, freertos

I'm using the EFM32WG360 MCU. I'm using the Gecko 5.0.0 SDK with FreeRTOS 9.0.0 with tickless mode (demo 2). That means that I'm using the RTC for tickless.

I haven't modified the demo's low_power_tick_management_RTC.c other than

- modifying the RTC clock to be LFRCO
- timer frequency to be 4Khz (instead of 4096Hz)
- no test timer

.

```
//#define lpINCLUDE_TEST_TIMER  1
```

What I'm seeing is that the RTC compare was set to some large value in the following code (line 304):

```
if( ulTickFlag != pdFALSE )
{
    /* The tick interrupt has already executed, although because this
    function is called with the scheduler suspended the actual tick
    processing will not occur until after this function has exited.
    Reset the reload value with whatever remains of this tick period. */
    ulReloadValue = ulReloadValueForOneTick - ulCountAfterSleep;
    RTC_CompareSet( 0, ulReloadValue );
```

ulReloadValueForOneTick has value of 4 and ulCountAfterSleep has value of 13.

Other variables:

- xModifiableIdleTime is 4
- ulReloadValue (before modification) is 3

What happens next is that in the next vPortSuppressTicksAndSleep function entry, ulCountBeforeSleep (line 225) gets some large value and then an assertion fails in vTaskStepTick.

Any idea on how could that happen? Could the RTC not interrupt in time or do an early interrupt?

I'll appreciate the help

Comment: Do you understand that (4 - 13) will result in "some large value" when the result is unsigned?

Comment: Yes, of course. That's why I've written down their values...